# Google Cloud Function Storage triggered by datastore entity insert

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

i have a datastore entity. I want to link it to a bucket (Cloud Storage), in order to trigger a storage function after each insert inside the datastore entity. i want the function to console.log the value of the insert. The documentation is really light and i didn't find any tutorial.

How do we do that ? thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by linking it to a bucket? Do you mean exporting to a GCS bucket? Also, there's no such thing as a Storage Function. Did you mean Cloud Function?

Comment: @Maxim yes and yes :) thank you

Comment: So export a Datastore Entity to a Cloud Storage bucket, trigger a Cloud Function with this event, which will console.log the values of the Datastore Entity. Is this want you want to do?

Comment: @Maxim That is exactly what i want to do bu the issue is i don't know and didn't manage to export it to a bucket i 've created. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, make sure the Cloud Storage bucket is located within the **[same region](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/locations#selecting_a_location)** as the Cloud Datastore database; or otherwise, it will not work. The location of the Datastore database is the project’s default location.

**1.** Got to Compute > Cloud Functions > Create Function to create and deploy the Cloud Function that will log the Datastore entity export metadata. Give the Function a name, set the Trigger to be `Cloud Storage`, and the Event Type `Finalize/Create`.

Use the Inline editor to write the source code for the runtime of your preference. I will use the Node.JS 6 runtime and the following code to log the Datastore entity export:

```
exports.myfunction = (event, callback) => {
  const file = event.data;

  console.log(`  Event: ${event.eventId}`);
  console.log(`  Event Type: ${event.eventType}`);
  console.log(`  Bucket: ${file.bucket}`);
  console.log(`  File: ${file.name}`);
  console.log(`  Metageneration: ${file.metageneration}`);
  console.log(`  Created: ${file.timeCreated}`);
  console.log(`  Updated: ${file.updated}`);

  callback();
};
```

You can find more examples using different runtimes [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#object_finalize).

**2.** Use the below `gcloud` command to [export](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#exporting_entities) the Cloud Datastore entity in the default namespace, to a Cloud Storage bucket.

```
gcloud datastore export --namespaces="(default)" gs://my-bucket
```

**3.** Go to Stackdriver > Logging > Logs and select the Cloud Function you have created from the first drop down list. You should see an output similar to this:

```
Event: undefined   
Event Type: undefined   
Bucket: my-bucket  
File: 2018-12-02T15:15:59_98240/2018-12-02T15:15:59_98240.overall_export_metadata
Metageneration: 1 
Created: 2018-12-02T15:16:06.460Z  
Updated: 2018-12-02T15:16:06.460Z  
Function execution took 16 ms, finished with> status: 'ok'
```

Comment: I 've followed the step but somethings missing or not  well-written:
in order to link Datastore to the bucket i've written in the console: gcloud datastore export --namespaces="(default)" gs://BUCKET_NAME
Then i 've created the function and linked it to the same bucket.
How to check if datastore and bucket are in the same region ? thanks

Comment: The region of the Datastore DB is the project’s default region. You can check it by running
gcloud compute project-info describe | grep "key: google" -A 1 in the Cloud Shell. The bucket's region is specified
at Cloud Storage > Browser > Location on the Cloud Console. If they don't match for you (regions), either create a new 
bucket in the same region as the Datastore DB, or change your project's default region and zone to the bucket's, following
this link: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/#change_your_default_zone_and_region_in_the_metadata_server

Comment: actually the function is well linked to the bucket, because i've uploaded a txt file in the bucket just to test the trigger , and i could see that the log inside the function. So the trigger works. @Maxim So the issue is between datastore and the bucket.